# Why does HTOP show exclamation mark next to uptime

Tags: linux, debian, uptime, htop

Here is the screenshot [image]

What does the (!) means next to the uptime ?

Comment: I have asked the maintainers of htop to remove it, as it causes confusion, but they disagreed, see https://github.com/htop-dev/htop/issues/614

Comment: @jorisw "Most people get the meaning of the (!) intuitively (we've had zero support requests for this)" - this looks like a blatant lie

Comment: Indeed, they're just not willing to make the change, and let go of an 'artistic' decision they made in error.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

htop adds an exclamation mark if the uptime is greater than 100 days.

From: https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/blob/0e8a02367ec7ca8f52b10de70938dfd07faed3ab/UptimeMeter.c#L41

Comment: The question is mis asked, so this doesnt answer my version of the question which is why does it do so / what it means. Does it mean wow look how good your server is, or does it mean, boy you need to reboot it?

Comment: @Pykler It means that when you *do* get around to rebooting, it might not come up.

Comment: @Navin You mean it may not come back up because it's been so long since a reboot that some component or similar failed during that time? Are there other reasons that it might not come back up?

Comment: Where is what the author of htop has to say: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351864

Answer (score 11):

It is letting you know that your server has been up for a long time. Basically anything over 100 days of uptime will produce an exclamation mark next to the uptime reading.

Comment: Aren't servers built and meant not to be rebooted often ?

Comment: @Alucard Yes, but this basically means the server has gone six months without a kernel update.

Comment: @thatotherguy not necessarily, at least with [ksplice](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ksplice) you don't need to reboot.

Comment: What, 100 days are now six months?

Comment: 100 days = 6 months in the metric system.

Comment: Where is what the author of htop has to say: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351864